# Using WMS in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wms

I am new to WMS.

I requested some data (I assumed it'd be in vector format).  I received a WMS link, which I opened and I am not totally sure how.

Could someone shed some light on how I opened this?

I am referring to *arcgis on vtransmap01.aot.state.vt.us* (in the picture below).

Why is the link *not* shown under Add WMS Server?

[image]

Comment: It's in the right spot, under your 'known' servers, the reason for multiple 'add server' icons is because each one has a different connection wizard but in the end all GIS Servers should be there regardless of the type. If it hasn't changed since the last time I looked, WMS is a raster service (the server compiles a raster from your extent and then sends it to you each refresh) and you can't modify the symbology, WFS is features which will allow you to change symbology and query features. If you need features you will have to contact them again for a data clip.

Comment: You can modify symbology of a WMS, by supplying SLD in the request.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @MichaelMiles-Stimson:

> It's in the right spot, under your 'known' servers, the reason for
>   multiple 'add server' icons is because each one has a different
>   connection wizard but in the end all GIS Servers should be there
>   regardless of the type. If it hasn't changed since the last time I
>   looked, WMS is a raster service (the server compiles a raster from
>   your extent and then sends it to you each refresh) and you can't
>   modify the symbology, WFS is features which will allow you to change
>   symbology and query features. If you need features you will have to
>   contact them again for a data clip.